# Problem with splitting string input in c# in a very specific way

Tags: c#

```
string input = "\"Hello, World!\" ! \"Some other string\"";
```

Hello, I am having a problem with finding a solution to this. You see, I want to Split the string in half by the ! separating the two "fake strings" inside the string. I am aware that I can use **String.Split()**, but what if there is an exclamation mark inside the "fake string"?

Would appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: what do you mean by "fake string" and what is your desired result?

Comment: You could use regular expressions to extract each internal or "fake" string. I'm assuming by "fake string" you mean the text inside the escaped double quotes `\"`.

Comment: Its better to use any other separator then `!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex: `"(.*)" ! "(.*)"`

https://regex101.com/r/4uBspp/1

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the seperator will always be formed from the string `\" ! \"` you can use the Split overload function by passing that string as part of the string array.

```
string input = "\"Hello, World!\" ! \"Some other string\"";
var data = input.Split(new string[] { "\" ! \"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to the others is to use a state machine-style approach - if your start and end string delimiters were different (e.g. if they were `<` and `>` instead of `"`) then this would work better to support nested strings than a regex approach.

```
void Main()
{
    var stateMachine = new StringSplitStateMachine();

    stateMachine.Split("hi"); // hi
    stateMachine.Split("hi!lo"); // hi, lo
    stateMachine.Split("\"hi!lo\""); // "hi!lo"
    stateMachine.Split("\"hi\"!lo"); // "hi", lo
}

public class StringSplitStateMachine
{
    private readonly char _splitCharacter;
    private readonly char _stringDelimiter;
    public StringSplitStateMachine(char splitCharacter = '!', char stringDelimiter = '"')   
    {
        _splitCharacter = splitCharacter;       
        _stringDelimiter = stringDelimiter;
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<string> Split(string input)
    {
        bool insideString =false;
        var currentString = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(var character in input)
        {
            if (character == _splitCharacter && !insideString)
            {
                yield return currentString.ToString();
                currentString.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                if (character == _stringDelimiter) 
                {
                    insideString = !insideString;
                }
                
                currentString.Append(character);
            }
        }
        
        if (currentString.Length > 0)
        {
            yield return currentString.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```